# segmentation fault (core dumped) in gnuradio-companion

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

when add a **QTGUI-sink** module in gnuradio-companion , gr just crashed with the following error:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

above this error, I noticed some warnings

```
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'qtgui_bercurve_sink')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'qtgui_const_sink_x')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'qtgui_edit_box_msg')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'qtgui_freq_sink_x')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'qtgui_histogram_sink_x')
Warning: docstring loader crashed too often
```

So I import Qtgui, but it was ok.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

env:
os: Ubuntu LTS 20.04

python: python3.8

GnuRadio: Gnuradio3.8.5

gcc:9.3.0

Comment: This problem occurs by building from source.  I solved this after reinstalled Gnuradio by  Prebuilt Binaries.

Comment: yeah, sounds like you were mixing some different builds of GNU Radio.